# How to translate =MATCH() formula into VBA

Tags: vba, excel

How could I use the following in VBA:

```
=MATCH(1,INDEX(($A$1:$A$6="id2")*($B$1:$B$6="day1"),),0)
```

this is what i have tried:

```
dim nrwo as integer
With Application.WorksheetFunction
    nrow=.MATCH(1,INDEX((range("a1:a6")="id2")*(range("b1:b6")="day1"),),0)
end with
```

it doesn't work, keeping telling me grammar errors

Comment: show what you have tried...

Comment: this is what i have tried:

With Application.WorksheetFunction
nrow=.MATCH(1,INDEX((range("a1:a6")="id2")*(range("b1:b6")="day1"),),0)
end with

it doesn't work, keeping telling me grammar errors

Comment: If I am reading the code in the comment correctly, you are trying to get VBA to do array operations, which it isn't able to do.  You either need to use a loop, or use Excel formulas.

Answer (score 3):

This will be

```
cl.Formula = "=MATCH(1,INDEX(($A$1:$A$6=""id2"")*($B$1:$B$6=""day1""),),0)"
```

Where cl is one cell (range object) You need double quotation marks inside the formula.

EDIT: Oh, it is array formula, istn't it? Sou you should use cl.FormulaArray

Comment: thanks a lot, this is really an easy way to solve my problem, thanks so much

Comment: @user8487819 if this solved your issue, please mark as ***Answered***

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the cell with the working Excel formula.
2. Run this code

---

```
Public Sub PrintMeUsefulFormula()

    Dim strFormula  As String
    Dim strParenth  As String

    strParenth = """"

    strFormula = Selection.Formula
    strFormula = Replace(strFormula, """", """""")

    strFormula = strParenth & strFormula & strParenth
    Debug.Print strFormula

End Sub
```

---

3. Copy the result in the immediate window.